# Unlink path not working after adding a folder

Tags: php, unlink, delete-file

I save the path to my images in my database. To delete these images, I get the path from the database.
This worked fine, until I added two folders to the path.
So far the path in my database looked like this (working!):
`/var/www/myproject/public/images/550d744bd91d16.7869` 
Now, it looks like this (not working!): 
 `/var/www/myproject/public/images/5/profile/550d744bd91d16.7869` 
**My Code**

```
    $folder_name = /var/www/myproject/public/images/ . $_GET['user_id'] . '/';
    $profile_folder = $folder_name . 'profile/';

    chmod($folder_name, 0777);
    chmod($profile_folder, 0777);

    // Get the images file path
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT image_path FROM images WHERE image_id = :image_id AND user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute(array(':image_id' => $image_id, ':user_id' => Session::get('user_id')));

    $img_path = $query->fetch();

    // Convert array to string
    $path = $img_path->image_path;

    $file = $path . '.jpg';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        // Delete the image file on the server
        unlink($file);
    } else {
        echo 'An error occured';
        return false;
    }
```

**What I tried so far**
The path is definitely correct. I triple checked in the database and outputted the variable multiple times.
Therefore, I thought it must be the directory permissions, however, I added the permissions to the code and nothing changed.
I am not getting any error message and I would be beyond thankful for any kind of help with this!

**Summary**
`file_exists(unlink($file))`
 returns FALSE. 
`unlink($file)`
 returns TRUE. 
The file permissions:

```
images  drwxrwxrwx 
5       drwxrwxrwx 
profile drwxrwxrwx 
image.jpg -rwxrwxrwx
```

Comment: Try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see if there's really an error

Comment: I already added that. And nothing... The file_exists() always returns FALSE and if I leave that out the unlink does not work either.

Comment: And what's inside `$file`?

Comment: /var/www/myproject/public/images/5/profile/550d744bd91d16.7869.jpg  which is exactly the path to the image.

Comment: So you are getting inside the 'if file exisits'? Try putting the unlink in a conditional, does PHP think it deleted it?

Comment: @chris85 I updated my question. Is that what you meant? Before the changes I did not get into the file_exists. So I did not get to the unlink.

Comment: I meant `if file exists` then `if unlink`.

Comment: @chris85 that is how it is in my first version of the question. There I get the error message. So it does not recognise that the file exists.

Comment: No, first version you you "if file exisits unlink". Updated version you have "unlink then does file exist". Check if file exists then try deleting it. Unlink returns true or false if process functions so see what it returns (aka put it in a conditional).

Comment: You are absolutely right! I am sorry about my misunderstanding. And yes, if I do this `if (unlink($file)) {` it does return true and runs the code in the if. So php thinks it deleted it.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you so much for all your help and patience! I added a summary of my problem to the question. If you have any guess to what might be wrong I would be very thankful!!